# How to decrypt HEX string with AES-128-GCM in C#

Tags: c#, security, encryption, hex, aes-gcm

I am trying to retrieve data from my Kamstrup energy meter and pass it on to Home Assistant.
I am getting data from the energy meter but it is encrypted. According to the documentation it is encrypted as follows: "**Data transport with AES-GCM-128 and key transport AES-128 key wrap (DLMS/COSEM suite 0).**"

I have received an encryption key and an authentication key in HEX format. But not sure how to use it. They only provide a very brief example in Python but i am really a long way from translating that into C#.

Microsoft have an example here to decrypt using AES: [AES decryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-5.0)
I have tried to build on this to get the data decrypted - but it does not work. I only get a weird string like "(oƒ¸Ž\u001aãÀ™\0:â«³\u0081)Ù7ÈS\u001bj\u0004OÏÜ.œ\u007f¨..." (abbreviated but is approximately 480 characters long).

As key and IV i pass the bytes from the authentication key and an encryption key.
Not sure how correct that is.

Kamstrup have provided a sample where the use authentication key: "AFB3F93E3E7204EDB3C27F96DBD51AE0" and encryption key "5AD84121D9D20B364B7A11F3C1B5827F"
to decrypt the following text:

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

and get

> 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

They then recommend using "GuruX DLMS Translator" to get XML data from the decrypted string.

I really am a newbie when it comes to encrypting/decrypting so really not sure what i am doing wrong in the decryption. At first glance it lookes to me as the wrong Encoding in the output. But i have no idea where to change the encoding.
I have spend hours now getting almost nowhere.

I have also tried different only decryption tools like "[scadacore.com](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/)" to just get an idea of the process. But i cannot make that work either.

Code used to decrypt so far.

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;
            aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            //aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.
            
            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    csDecrypt.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);

                    //using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    //{

                    //    // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                    //    // and place them in a string.
                    //    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    //}
                }

                plaintext = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(msDecrypt.ToArray());
                var plainTextLength = plaintext.Length;
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
```

Could any of you please point me in the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am going nowhere fast.

Thank you!

**EDIT.**
It seems there was missing som information about security tag and nonce. Here is the documentation about how the string is put together.

Tag: 1 byte - System title: len + 8 bytes - Length: x bytes - Security header: 1 or 5 bytes - Cipher text: y bytes - Auth tag: 12 bytes

**Attempt 1:**

Both of the following attempts fail.
The first one fails with: "The computed authentication tag did not match the input authentication tag."
The BouncyCastle solution fails with: "mac check in GCM failed".

I have had som help to get the Python example up and running and it decrypts the data exactly accoring to the documentation.
I have checked all the values from the Python code with the ones in C#. Everything is identical. It seems to be the auth tag giving problems - but it is the same in both Python and C# so i am assuming it has something to do with the C# code.
Fails at: "aesGcm.Decrypt(nonce, cipherBytes, authTag, plainBytes);"

```
    namespace AesGcmNetCoreTestApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var cipherText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
            cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "");
            var cipherTextBytes = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(cipherText);

            var encryptionKey = "5AD84121D9D20B364B7A11F3C1B5827F";
            var encryptionKeyBytes = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(encryptionKey);
            var authenticationKey = "AFB3F93E3E7204EDB3C27F96DBD51AE0";
            var authenticationKeyBytes = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(authenticationKey);
            var peek = ConvertByteArrayToString(encryptionKeyBytes);

            var systemTitle = cipherTextBytes.SelectIndexRange(2, 10);
            var initializationVector = systemTitle.MergeWith(cipherTextBytes.SelectIndexRange(14, 18));
            var additionalAuthenticatedData = cipherTextBytes.SelectIndexRange(13, 14).MergeWith(authenticationKeyBytes);
            var authenticationTag = cipherTextBytes.SelectIndexRange(cipherTextBytes.Length - 12, cipherTextBytes.Length);

            var res = DecryptGcm(cipherTextBytes, encryptionKeyBytes, authenticationTag, initializationVector);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    static byte[] DecryptGcm(byte[] cipherBytes, byte[] encKey, byte[] authTag, byte[] nonce)
    {
        byte[] plainBytes = new byte[cipherBytes.Length];

        using (AesGcm aesGcm = new AesGcm(encKey))
        {
            aesGcm.Decrypt(nonce, cipherBytes, authTag, plainBytes);
        }

        return plainBytes;
    }

    public static string ConvertByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }

    public static byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
            .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
            .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
            .ToArray();
    }



}
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static byte[] SelectIndexRange(this byte[] bytes, int from, int to)
    {
        if (bytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Bytes array cannot be empty.");
        if (bytes.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Bytes array cannot be empty.");

        if (bytes.Length < from) throw new ArgumentException("From index cannot be lower than length!");
        if (bytes.Length < to) throw new ArgumentException("To index cannot be higher than length.");

        var res = bytes.Skip(from).Take(to - from).ToArray();
        return res;
    }

    public static byte[] MergeWith(this byte[] origByte, byte[] mergeWithBytes)
    {
        if (origByte.Length == 0 && mergeWithBytes.Length == 0) return Array.Empty<byte>();

        var totalLength = origByte.Length + mergeWithBytes.Length;

        var resBytes = new byte[totalLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < origByte.Length; i++)
        {
            resBytes[i] = origByte[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mergeWithBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            var index = i + origByte.Length;
            resBytes[index] = mergeWithBytes[i];
        }

        return resBytes;
    }

}
}
```

I also tried BouncyCastle with the same inputs.
Fails at: "cipher.DoFinal(plaintextBytes, offset);"

```
private static string DecryptWithBouncyCastle(byte[] ciphertext, byte[] nonce, byte[] tag, byte[] key)
    {
        var plaintextBytes = new byte[ciphertext.Length];

        var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
        var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), tag.Length * 8, nonce);
        cipher.Init(false, parameters);

        var bcCiphertext = ciphertext.Concat(tag).ToArray();

        var offset = cipher.ProcessBytes(bcCiphertext, 0, bcCiphertext.Length, plaintextBytes, 0);
        cipher.DoFinal(plaintextBytes, offset);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintextBytes);
    }
```

Comment: You need to determine IV, AAD and tag. [Here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/TroubledStingyClosedsource) you can find an (online executable) Python code from which you can derive how to determine these parameters.

Comment: "As key and IV i pass the bytes from the authentication key and an encryption key. Not sure how correct that is." It's not correct, a key is not an IV, probably the IV is prefixed. Look up the protocol!

Comment: The main problem here is the determination of the parameters. Your current solution is already quite close: Of course you may only decrypt the _actual_ ciphertext: `var actualCipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.SelectIndexRange(18, cipherTextBytes.Length - 12)`. If you then also pass the `additionalAuthenticatedData` in the 5th parameter of the `aesGcm.Decrypt()` call, decryption succeeds and the expected plaintext results, see online on .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rCzMqM

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you Topaco!

Answer (score 1):

There is no enough information, but I'm sure that you are using the wrong API. For AES-GCM you should use [AesGcm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-5.0) class, like this:

```
static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherBytes, byte[] encKey, byte[] authTag, byte[] nonce)
{
    byte[] plainBytes = new byte[cipherBytes.Length];

    using (AesGcm aesGcm = new AesGcm(encKey))
    {
        aesGcm.Decrypt(nonce, cipherBytes, authTag, plainBytes);
    }

    return plainBytes;
}
```

You didn't provide nonce and authentication tag, so I can't test it with your sample data.

Comment: Thx Igor. I have added info from the documentation about these for future reference. I will try to proceed with your method and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: I have now tried the code and it does not work for me. I have updated my question to reflect my attempt at two solutions. I have also included more information on isolating the different elements like auth tag. I would appreciate any advice you could give me. Thank you.